# Return value of math.sqrt

Tags: c#, function, return, math.sqrt

I have been try to draw the function of y^2=4*a*x but I have run into a problem. when I use the math.sqrt function to find the square root of a value which has two answer +or- something i only get the positive value. i.e if i found the sqrt of 4 it would return +2 instead of + or -2.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Because that's the definition of the function... If you want the negative value, you can always invert what you are given to get it...

Comment: How do you expect a function to return ±2? Are you using a quantum computer?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own method to return both values:

```
public static IEnumerable<double> Sqrt(double d)
{
    var result = Math.Sqrt(d);
    yield return result;
    yield return -result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply the answer with -1 also and get both.

Answer (score 0):

If you read [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sqrt.aspx) (MSDN is really complete and well made, use it before asking questions) you will see that with a parameter 0 or positive, `Math.Sqrt` returns only "*The positive square root of d.*"

If you need the negative value, you have to do it yourself, for example like this :

```
double value = 4;
double positiveSqrt = Math.Sqrt(value);
double negativeSqrt = positiveSqrt * -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a function that returns both positive and negative square roots, you could write your own pretty easily:

```
public static double[] Sqrts(double d) {
    var v = Math.Sqrt(d);
    return v == 0 ? new[] { v } : new[] { v, -v };
}
```

Comment: What if you take the square root of zero?

Comment: @EricLippert Good point. It *might* useful to return a `-0.0` in that case, but I suspect OP isn't interested in such quirks.